# How would you determine the Miller input and output capacitance for the amplifier in the figure?

Tags: capacitor, frequency, capacitance, high-frequency, jfet

[image]

[image]
When I calculate the Miller input and output capacitance I get; Cin(Miller) as 6.38pF and Cout(Miller) as 5.66pF. However, these values are incorrect.

Comment: How did you calculate them? Show your potentially erroneous calculation please.

Comment: I have attached my method of working out the values.

Comment: I would want to see a **small signal equivalent circuit** which includes the capacitances that are inside the JFET. In the schematic you show **there is no Miller cap. present** so there is no Miller effect. Yes I know it sits in the JFET but I want to see it in a (small signal) schematic.

Comment: This more of a theory based question and I am only required to find the Miller input and output capacitance using the figure above.

Comment: Do they ask you about total Cin? Or just a miller capacitance?

Comment: Just the Miller capacitance